# Installation of MS Build Tools fails on Windows Docker Container

Tags: docker, visual-c++

I'm trying to set up a Windows container for a CI pipeline.
My Project uses C++ and CMake, so I'm using the Microsoft Build Tools installer.

*Note: I do not intend to use any part of the .NET framework for my project*

Unfortunately, the installation of MS Build Tools in my Docker container fails with an exit code of 5003 and no error message.

I haven't been able to find an explanation of this return code. I was wondering if anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:10.0.14393.1480

ADD https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe  C:\\tmp\\vs-build-tools.exe

RUN C:\\tmp\\vs-build-tools.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --includeRecommended --quiet --passive --norestart --wait --nocache

RUN powershell -NoProfile -InputFormat None -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))"
RUN %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin\choco.exe install -y git

ENTRYPOINT C:\BuildTools\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat &&
CMD ["powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

And I'm building the container with this batch script (Username has been replaced):

```
docker image rm someusername/cmake-msvc
docker build -t someusername/cmake-msvc -m 8g .
docker push someusername/cmake-msvc
```

I've read that [these Windows containers require](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-agent-docker/issues/46) [a large amount of storage space](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container-issues?view=vs-2019), so I've increased the available space by setting `storage-opts`:

```
"storage-opts": [
    "size=120G"
]
```

This is the console output I get when building, it takes a while before the build crashes (I haven't timed it, but I'm guessing it's somewhere between 20 and 40 minutes):

```
docker build -t someusername/cmake-msvc -m 8g .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   1.29MB
Step 1/7 : FROM microsoft/windowsservercore:10.0.14393.1480
 ---> 2c42a1b4dea8
Step 2/7 : ADD https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe   C:\\tmp\\vs-build-tools.exe
Downloading [==================================================>]  1.286MB/1.286MB

 ---> 1891bae28aa1
Step 3/7 : RUN C:\\tmp\\vs-build-tools.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --includeRecommended --quiet --passive --norestart --wait --nocache
 ---> Running in aa6061b7134e
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1028\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\2052\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1029\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1036\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\3082\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1040\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1031\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1033\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1055\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1046\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1042\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1045\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1041\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\HelpFile\1049\help.html...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Microsoft.VisualStudio.RemoteControl.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Common.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Configuration.Interop.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Download.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Engine.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Utilities.Internal.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\Newtonsoft.Json.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\zh-Hans\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\zh-Hant\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\cs\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\pt-BR\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\tr\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\es\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\de\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\fr\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\it\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\pl\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\ko\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\ja\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\ru\vs_setup_bootstrapper.resources.dll...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.config...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.exe.config...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\detection.json...
Preparing: C:\Users\ContainerAdministrator\AppData\Local\Temp\e86ca78527dcfbd3cf\vs_bootstrapper_d15\vs_setup_bootstrapper.json...
The command 'cmd /S /C C:\\tmp\\vs-build-tools.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --includeRecommended --quiet --passive --norestart --wait --nocache' returned a non-zero code: 5003
```

I've noticed that [this Github user](https://github.com/Microsoft/vs-dockerfiles/issues/5) is experiencing a similar issue, although no answer has been given yet.
I've also read [this post](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/81514/2017-build-tools-fails-to-install-on-windows-serve.html) on the MS Developer Community, where people seem to recommend using an older or a newer version of the windosservercore image ([This blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/installing-build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017-in-a-docker-container/) seems to give similar recommendations). That's why I'm using `10.0.14393.1480`, but unfortunately to no avail.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve your problem? I read the GitHub link that you posted, and there they wrote that there was some network issues when building the docker images.

Comment: I never did unfortunately

Comment: When I build an image using the MS Build tool installer it works fine on my development PC, but its failing in my Circle CI pipeline.

Answer (score 4):

I've been having the non-zero code 1 as an exit code, with everything quite similar to how you have it, and it had me quite baffled.

What helped me was to change the line corresponding to `RUN C:\\tmp\\vs-build-tools.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --includeRecommended --quiet --passive --norestart --wait --nocache` into:

```
RUN C:\\tmp\\vs-build-tools.exe --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --includeRecommended --quiet --passive --norestart --wait --nocache || exit 0
```

Which reports an exit code of 0 even when it fails. While I am fully aware that this is in general a very bad idea, when I run `docker run -it build-container cmd` I see that my build tools have been installed correctly.

### Edit:

You might want to run this aswell, to install any SDK-packages that were not installed by VS2017 (you can download the SDK from Microsoft's website):

`RUN powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command Start-Process -FilePath "C:\tmp\winsdksetup_17763.exe" -ArgumentList '/Quiet /NoRestart' -Wait`

Otherwise I can also recommend the method described by Microsoft [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/advanced-build-tools-container?view=vs-2019) to collect logs from the installation. The logs can later on be submitted to Microsoft to get support.

A possible work-around for you is to install the build-tools via Chocolatey. I've been previously using the following, I'm sure you can find similar packages to meet your needs:

```
RUN choco install -y visualstudio2017community --version 15.9.7.0
RUN choco install -y visualstudio2017-workload-nativedesktop
RUN choco install -y visualcpp-build-tools
```